# Splitting a string into different columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, split

I am currently struggling splitting up a string to output each value into their own columns.

Here is the following string.

```
DECLARE @text NVARCHAR(MAX) = '[Reference]:[randomValue1] [Type]:[randomValue2] [Test]:[randomValue3]'
```

I would like to output the randomValue1, randomValue2 & randomValue3 in separate columns.

**PLEASE NOTE**: the delimiter on the system is a line feed and not a whitespace

Comment: What database software are you using, e.g. Sybase? What version? What have you tried? Is the order of the columns significant, i.e. you can't use a function like [string_split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) that doesn't maintain the order? Did a search for `[tsql] split delimited string into columns` reveal nothing of use?

Comment: The ones I've searched up on google did not help me as it return the wrong values. I am using SQL Server 14.0.3192.2

Comment: However @HABO I want to use this on a different variety of SQL Servers, for the future. Last time I tried string_split, it printed an error that SQL does not know what function it is

Comment: use your own string split function like https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Various options, but you should not use `SUBSTRING()`, `CHARINDEX()` etc.

Try one of these:

```
DECLARE @text NVARCHAR(MAX) = '[Reference]:[randomValue1] [Type]:[randomValue2] [Test]:[randomValue3]';
```

--These two statements create attribute-centered XML and use XQuery to read from there (working down to v2005):

```sql
--XML like this: <x Reference="randomValue1" Type="randomValue2" Test="randomValue3" />

--With known columns
SELECT Reference = A.Casted.value('(x/@*[local-name()="Reference"])[1]','nvarchar(max)')
      ,[Type] = A.Casted.value('(x/@*[local-name()="Type"])[1]','nvarchar(max)')
      ,[Test] = A.Casted.value('(x/@*[local-name()="Test"])[1]','nvarchar(max)')
FROM(VALUES(CAST(CONCAT('<x ',REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@text,']:[','="'),']','"'),'[',''),'/>') AS XML)))A(Casted)

--With unknown columns
SELECT [name]  = attr.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)') 
      ,[value] = attr.value('.','nvarchar(max)') 
FROM(VALUES(CAST(CONCAT('<x ',REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@text,']:[','="'),']','"'),'[',''),'/>') AS XML)))A(Casted)
CROSS APPLY A.Casted.nodes('/x/@*') B(attr);
```

--These two transform your list to JSON (needs v2016+)

```sql
--JSON like this: { "Reference":"randomValue1","Type":"randomValue2","Test":"randomValue3" }

--With known columns
SELECT A.*
FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('{ ',REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@text,'[','"'),']','"'),' ',','),' }'))
WITH([Reference] NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,[Type]      NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,[Test]      NVARCHAR(MAX)) A ;


--With unknwon columns
SELECT A.*
FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('{ ',REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@text,'[','"'),']','"'),' ',','),' }')) A
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a way to return exactly the value inside the brackets.

Sample Code:

```
DECLARE @testData NVARCHAR(500)= '[Locality]:[70648X]' + CHAR(13) + '[Category]:[Non-Criminal (OB) - Suspicious Activities - Persons]' + CHAR(13) + '[Vehicle Make]:[BMW]' + CHAR(13) + '[Vehicle Model]:[7 Series]' + CHAR(13) + '[Vehicle Colour]:[White]' + CHAR(13) + '[Registration Number]:[DBIIIIGP]' + CHAR(13) + '[Identification Markings]:[Chrome Trimming]' + CHAR(13) + '[Suspicious Actions]:[Loitering]'

-- Vehicle
SELECT SUBSTRING(@testData, (SELECT CHARINDEX('[Locality]:[', @testData) + 12), ((SELECT CHARINDEX('[Category]:[', @testData) -3) - (SELECT CHARINDEX(CHAR(13) + '[Locality]:[', @testData) + 12 AS MatchPosition))) -- Locality
SELECT SUBSTRING(@testData, (SELECT CHARINDEX('[Category]:[', @testData) + 12), ((SELECT CHARINDEX('[Vehicle Make]:[', @testData) -3) - (SELECT CHARINDEX(CHAR(13) + '[Category]:[', @testData) + 12 AS MatchPosition))) -- Category
SELECT SUBSTRING(@testData, (SELECT CHARINDEX('[Vehicle Make]:[', @testData) + 16), ((SELECT CHARINDEX('[Vehicle Model]:[', @testData) -2) - (SELECT CHARINDEX(CHAR(13) + '[Vehicle Make]:[', @testData) +17 AS MatchPosition))) -- Vehicle Make
SELECT SUBSTRING(@testData, (SELECT CHARINDEX('[Vehicle Model]:[', @testData) + 17), ((SELECT CHARINDEX('[Vehicle Colour]:[', @testData) -3) - (SELECT CHARINDEX(CHAR(13) + '[Vehicle Model]:[', @testData) +17 AS MatchPosition))) -- Vehicle Model
SELECT SUBSTRING(@testData, (SELECT CHARINDEX('[Vehicle Colour]:[', @testData) + 18), ((SELECT CHARINDEX('[Registration Number]:[', @testData) -4) - (SELECT CHARINDEX(CHAR(13) + '[Vehicle Colour]:[', @testData) +17 AS MatchPosition))) -- Vehicle Colour
SELECT SUBSTRING(@testData, (SELECT CHARINDEX('[Registration Number]:[', @testData) + 23), ((SELECT CHARINDEX('[Identification Markings]:[', @testData) -4) - (SELECT CHARINDEX(CHAR(13) + '[Registration Number]:[', @testData) +22 AS MatchPosition))) -- Registration Number
SELECT SUBSTRING(@testData, (SELECT CHARINDEX('[Identification Markings]:[', @testData) + 27), ((SELECT CHARINDEX('[Suspicious Actions]:[', @testData) -8) - (SELECT CHARINDEX(CHAR(13) + '[Identification Markings]:[', @testData) +22 AS MatchPosition))) -- Identification Markings
SELECT right(@testData, charindex('[', reverse(@testData) + '[') - 1) -- Suspicious Actions

-- Person
SET @testData = '[Locality]:[70648X]' + CHAR(13) + '[Category]:[Non-Criminal (OB) - Suspicious Activities - Persons]' + CHAR(13) + '[Person Gender]:[Male]' + CHAR(13) + '[Person Race]:[African]' + CHAR(13) + '[Identification Markings]:[He was wearing glasses]' + CHAR(13) + '[Suspicious Actions]:[Loitering]'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@testData, (SELECT CHARINDEX('[Locality]:[', @testData) + 12), ((SELECT CHARINDEX('[Category]:[', @testData) -3) - (SELECT CHARINDEX(CHAR(13) + '[Locality]:[', @testData) + 12 AS MatchPosition))) -- Locality
SELECT SUBSTRING(@testData, (SELECT CHARINDEX('[Category]:[', @testData) + 12), ((SELECT CHARINDEX('[Person Gender]:[', @testData) -3) - (SELECT CHARINDEX(CHAR(13) + '[Category]:[', @testData) + 12 AS MatchPosition))) -- Category
SELECT SUBSTRING(@testData, (SELECT CHARINDEX('[Person Gender]:[', @testData) + 17), ((SELECT CHARINDEX('[Person Race]:[', @testData) -3) - (SELECT CHARINDEX(CHAR(13) + '[Person Gender]:[', @testData) +17 AS MatchPosition))) --Person Gender
SELECT SUBSTRING(@testData, (SELECT CHARINDEX('[Person Race]:[', @testData) + 15), ((SELECT CHARINDEX('[Identification Markings]:[', @testData) -3) - (SELECT CHARINDEX(CHAR(13) + '[Person Race]:[', @testData) +15 AS MatchPosition))) -- Person Race
SELECT SUBSTRING(@testData, (SELECT CHARINDEX('[Identification Markings]:[', @testData) + 27), ((SELECT CHARINDEX('[Suspicious Actions]:[', @testData) -8) - (SELECT CHARINDEX(CHAR(13) + '[Identification Markings]:[', @testData) +22 AS MatchPosition))) -- Identification Markings
SELECT right(@testData, charindex('[', reverse(@testData) + '[') - 1) -- Suspicious Actions
```